# How can I get image title using Wikipedia API

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia-api

Suppose, that I got URLs of images on the page,

```
 for i in wiki.images:
    print (i)
```

Is there easy way to get images titles?

Comment: what exactly are you getting in i can you give us a hint plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try:**

If you are looping through all the urls of the images then you can try

```
for i in wiki.images:
    i.split('/')[-1]  # -1 because the name is at the last part of the url
```

So the above code will give you the image name.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to get are the image tag's title attribute (i.e., from the HTML), you could do something akin to:

```py
import wikipedia
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class WikipediaImageParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'img':
            try:
                print(dict(attrs)['title'])
            except KeyError as e:
                return # do nothing

page = wikipedia.page("History_of_Japan")
parser = WikipediaImageParser()
parser.feed(page.html())
```

You can parse the HTML to get a dict of the attributes for each image and then just check if there is a title attribute.